EF and AsNotracking issue
I am trying to insert new data in clientuser table as below
    var newClientUsers = new List<Entities.ClientUser>();

    var existingClientUsers = await mycontext.ClientUser.AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

Here variable clientUsers is populated with already available data in DB
    var clientUserList = clientUsers.Select(s =>
        new Entities.ClientUser
        {
            UserName = s.UserName,
            OrganizationId = s.OrganizationId
        }).ToList();

    newClientUsers = clientUserList.Except(existingClientUsers, new ClientUserComparer()).ToList();

Here ClientUserComparer compares both of the fields of class
    if (newClientUsers.Count > 0)
    {
        await mycontext.ClientUser.AddRange(newClientUsers);
        await mycontext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{DateTime.UtcNow} NoClientUsersAdded");
    }

This method fails to add data and gives error
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ClientUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for is already being tracked.
However i do not get issue when I remove AsNoTracking() from query or use AddRangeAsync. I want to understand what is the correct scenario for using AsNotracking for inserting data.
if you have any reference please share.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

OrganizationId = s.OrganizationId replace with Organization = s.Organization. If there is no such property, then create it.

However, this code is very inefficient and should be completely rewritten.

Also if there is any guideline to AsNotracking with AddRangeAsync or any standard document please share

Change Tracking in EF Core - this fully describes the behavior when adding entities.

What's the primary key of ClientUser? You have duplicate key values, that's not the same as duplicates based on those two compared properties.

Actually there is no primary key rather there is composite key with username and organizationId in ClientUser table

So that's the primary key (PKs can also be composite). It's not clear why you get this issue and it's even more unclear how removing AsNoTracking() would solve it. If you remove AsNoTracking() there's nothing attached to the context when you do AddRange unless the context has been used before it enters the visible code. We can't see where it comes from or what its lifecycle is. (BTW, uinsg AddRangeAsync shouldn't make a difference and you probably shouldn't use it anyway).

Using context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView helped me to fix the issue.

using context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView  helped me to fix the issue. There i identified that Since ClientUser table references Organization table and a change in ClientUser table was actually throwing error due to foreign key constraint
